# Posting Image with array parameters using AFNetworking 2.0 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to post an image with a parameter (categories) that is an array. If I leave this parameter out, I can submit fine. However, if I leave it in, my server throws an error because the array value doesn't seem to be getting serialized correctly.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
    @"auth_token" : authToken,
    @"title" : title,
    @"categories" : @[1,2,3]
}];

return [[MyHTTPSessionManager sharedManager] POST:path parameters:dict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                name:@"image"
                            fileName:@"image.jpg"
                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:nil failure:nil];
```

Looking at my server logs, this is how categories is coming across:

```
Parameters: {"categories"=>"(\n    1,\n    2,\n    3\n)", … }
```

And I need it to look like:

```
Parameters: {"categories"=>[1,2,3], … }
```

I've tried setting my instance of AFHTTPSessionManager's requestSerializer to `[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]` but that doesn't seem to help.

How can I properly POST an image + parameters? I'd like to avoid falling back to AFHTTPRequestOperation.

Thanks!

Comment: Try upgrading to the newest version of AFNetworking.  I believe this was fixed in https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1388, which I think was rolled into AFNetworking 2.0.1.

Comment: If the newest version doesn't work, just pull the latest commit.

Comment: well there went two hours of my day :). thanks. if you post this as an answer i'll award it to you.

Comment: No prob.  It pays to keep an eye on the issue trackers for 3rd party libraries you rely on :)

Comment: Strictly, you can't send hierarchically structured data in form parameters. There's no standard for this. What AFN does, is some custom thing. It's not guaranteed that a server will know how to parse the value of the parameter. The safest is likely to use "application/json" for the content type of the part where the parameters will be transferred. You might try: `appendPartWithHeaders:body:` to specify the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to the newest version of AFNetworking. I believe this was fixed in [github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1388](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1388), which I think was rolled into AFNetworking 2.0.1.  If the newest version doesn't work, just pull the latest commit.